# Can't set AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer as diffuse contents in SceneKit on Apple Silicon (M1)

Tags: swift, cocoa, avfoundation, scenekit

I'm trying to show an `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` on a SceneKit material.

EDIT: The contents of the preview layer comes from my USB connected iOS device.

1. The code linked below **works** when I do it with an `NSView`'s layer, so that part should be ok
2. The whole thing seems to work on Intel, but not Apple Silicon
3. The entire [project is here](https://github.com/mortenjust/Capture-device/blob/main/Capture%20device/ViewController.swift) - all the code is in the `ViewController`

What happens?

Bad Access crash.
[image]
[image]

What have I tried?

1. Using an `NSView`'s layer - works
2. Not setting a size on the layer - Metal crash (height is 0, width is 0 - this is expected in Big Sur)
3. Setting the layer's size to exactly the size derived from the input's ports dimensions - same crash
4. Making sure the layer isn't shown else where (as you'll see in the code)

UPDATE: Here's the crash log from running `detach` in lldb:
https://gist.github.com/mortenjust/4470c8e9e8ca1dc3043388b8b2886703

Comment: I tried holding on to the `CALayer` by setting it as a property on `ViewController` - still crashes

Comment: I tried enabling Address Sanitizer in the Scheme, but Xcode doesn't pause execution before it crashes

Comment: I tried enabling Zombie Objects in the Scheme, still crashes

Comment: I tried setting the `AVCaptureDevice` as the `contents` - doesn't crash, but shows a white material rather than the feed (docs say this only works on iOS, so I guess that's expected)

Answer (score 0):

I see a crash too but it's a simple `nil` unwrapping in the following line:

```swift
AVCaptureDevice.devices(for: .muxed).first!
```

Changing `.muxed` to `.video` fixed the crash.

---

Then for a better use of resources it's possible to directly use the device as follows:

```swift
@IBAction func start(_ sender: Any) {
    AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { granted in
        print("granted")
    }
    
    let discoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: .video, position: .front)
    let device = discoverySession.devices.first!
    boxNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = device
}
```

Just make sure the view is continuously redrawing so that new video frames are drawn:

```swift
sceneView.rendersContinuously = true
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my video source is my iOS device connected via USB (edited question to clarify). That explains why you got the unwrapping crash. 

For that reason, `DiscoverySession` won't discover the iOS device (or I don't know how to do it). Also, can you confirm that you are on an Apple Silicon Mac?

Comment: Works for me on an Apple Silicon Mac mini and an iPhone 12 Pro. I'd suggest running `detach` in lldb to let the process crash and obtain a crash report for you to share.

Comment: That is strange, I'm using an M1 Mac Mini (8Gb) and an iPhone 12 Pro. Here's the crash log from the `detach` - I'm not sure what to look for, though: https://gist.github.com/mortenjust/4470c8e9e8ca1dc3043388b8b2886703

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but I (and my users) also can't record to a file outside of SceneKit, also only on the M1. I made a separate SO post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67837309/cant-record-iphone-screen-on-apple-silicon

Answer (score 0):

From the crash log when learn that

1. The crash was triggered by ASan (see [AddressSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html))
2. Under `libMTLCapture.dylib` which is the library used to debug Metal in Xcode

I would [disable the GPU Frame Capture debug option](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/frame_capture_debugging_tools/enabling_frame_capture) in Xcode and see if the crash goes away. If it does I would file a Feedback to Apple.

```
Thread 2 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826c0cec __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000103beb384 pthread_kill + 292
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000182639864 abort + 104
3   libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib  0x0000000102be5e4c __sanitizer::Abort() + 64
4   libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib  0x0000000102be5788 __sanitizer::Die() + 208
5   libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib  0x0000000102bcf238 __asan::ScopedInErrorReport::~ScopedInErrorReport() + 420
6   libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib  0x0000000102bcd06c __asan::ReportDeadlySignal(__sanitizer::SignalContext const&) + 148
7   libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib  0x0000000102bcc950 __asan::AsanOnDeadlySignal(int, void*, void*) + 96
8   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x0000000182739c44 _sigtramp + 56
9   libMTLCapture.dylib             0x0000000103a96eb0 0x1039e0000 + 749232
10  com.apple.SceneKit              0x00000001a0ac1d50 __92-[SCNTextureCoreAnimationSource _resizeLayer:toSize:updateLayer:updateTransform:caRenderer:]_block_invoke + 824
11  libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib  0x0000000102bc7e28 __wrap_dispatch_group_async_block_invoke + 188
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000103b401d8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000103b41d20 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000103b58d04 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1664
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000103b5939c _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 140
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000103be74b8 _pthread_wqthread + 216
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000103be6228 start_wqthread + 8
```