# Can't record iPhone screen on Apple Silicon

Tags: swift, avfoundation, apple-silicon

I have a simple capture session set up to record my iPhone over USB from my Mac Mini M1.

When I try to record a capture session to file, nothing is written to disk, and the console outputs the same error message over and over again.

I can reproduce this issue on Apple Silicon only. The exact same code works on Intel.

STEPS

1. Allow screen capture with `kCMIOHardwarePropertyAllowScreenCaptureDevices`
2. Find the iPhone via `AVCaptureDevice.devices:for` - muxed
3. Create a capture device input with that device
4. Start the session, and display its preview layer. This works.
5. Tell the output to start recording
6. After a few seconds, tell output to stop recording

**Expected:**
A file to be found at the given file URL. This is the case on my Intel-based Mac.

**Actual:**
On Apple Silicon, no file is written, and the Xcode console fills up with this error message:

```
2021-06-04 14:00:23.379063+0200 Device Recording Demo[4786:102932] [] CMIO_Unit_Convertor_VideoToolboxCompressor.cpp:1958:doCompressBuffer [0x14683c800] EXCEPTION ON ERROR -67447
```

Full repo:

https://github.com/mortenjust/Device-Recording-Bug-Demo/blob/main/Device%20Recording%20Demo/ViewController.swift