# Error while capturing iOS Device screen on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I am trying to capture the iOS device's Screen In macOS. While capturing the mirrored iOS device screen we have had an issue:

STEPS

1. Get connect iPhone with a USB cable to your MacBook.

```
let discoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.externalUnknown], mediaType:.muxed, position: .unspecified)
let device = discoverySession.devices
```

2. Preview connected device
3. start to record the device session

Expected: A file to be found at the given file URL. This is the case on my Intel-based Mac.

Actual: On Apple Silicon, no file is written, and the Xcode console fills up with this error message:

> CMIO_Unit_Convertor_VideoToolboxCompressor.cpp:1958:doCompressBuffer [0x14683c800] EXCEPTION ON ERROR -67447

Comment: Same unresolved issue + reproducing repo 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67837309/cant-record-iphone-screen-on-apple-silicon

Comment: Hi, @MortenJ....any progress in this? Are you able to fix it?

Comment: It seems to be resolved in Monterrey for me. Apple responded to a similar Radar issue and mentioned that it might not make it into Big Sur, and more likely Monterrey—and it was. So maybe this is the same.